# insane number of continuation lines in fortran (ifort)

Tags: fortran, fortran90, intel-fortran

apparently, a limit exists in the number of allowed continuation lines in Fortran compilers. I have a temporary pathological case (made for quick testing purposes) where I am required to initialize a huge array without opening files or do any trickery, just slap data in as literals. The array is quite large (360000 entries).

How can I set the limit of the compiler to unlimited, or what alternative strategy can I use to host this array initialization ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about any compiler settings for unlimited continuation lines, but I would suggest these alternatives:

- assign each value on a single line
- put the values in a file and read it :)
- call a C function to fill your fortran array

Comment: I ended up doing the first one you propose. I can't read from file and I can't interface with C.

Comment: @Rook : The code is already messy enough. I need something reliable and compiled in. I am doing testing and debugging, not something to release.

Comment: @Stefano - Well, it will certanly be less messy if you don't hardcode the array values. Reading them from a file is surely not messy, nor unreliable. (Although, on the side not, I'm not sure from your question if I undestand correctly. You're hardcoding 360000 different array values? )

Comment: @Rook : It is messy and unreliable in my setup.

Answer (score 4):

You could assign them in batches using implicit `DO` loops, up to the continuation limit imposed by your compiler:

```
REAL :: xarray(360000)

DATA (xarray(i) i=1,100) /1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, &
    7.0, 8.0, &
...
    98.0, 99.0, 100.0 /

 DATA (xarray(i) i=101,200) /101.0, 102.0, 103.0, 104.0, 105.0, 106.0, &
    107.0, 108.0, &
...
    198.0, 199.0, 200.0 /
```

I've seen this in a lot of scientific Fortran code.

Answer (score 0):

Write some code to create your source files with data from a text file. Split the assignments by row or something to help avoid create one huge statement to initialize the array in one fell swoop. Remember code that generates code can be quite flexible.